# Geb radio button in chrome not working

Tags: grails, spock, geb

In my geb test I check a radio button with this code:

```
radioSelect = name
```

Definition:

```
radioSelect(wait: true) { $('input[name=rr]')}
```

This works fine in firefox, but in chrome the radio button is not checked.
No exception is thrown.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Try to enable the navigator's console to see if there is no error (specially with the JavaScript).
Also, you can try the following syntax : `$("input[name='rr']")`, which should be better ;)

Comment: Can I check for javascript errors in my programm? Or do I have to look in the browser?

Comment: @Peter i think above comment meant browser console

Comment: Yes, I meant the browser console. I wonder if there is a waa in selenium to check javascript errors

Answer (score 0):

Without more code (html code of the radio, full spec code) I don't know why is failing. I only could suggest trying any of this methods:

1. Using RadioButton module: http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#radio-buttons-module
2. Is this radio wrapped inside a form? If not, wrapp it and then try calling this way:

   $('form').*youRadioName* = 'desiredSelectedValue'

   assert $('form').*youRadioName* == 'desiredSelectedValue'